Is it possible to draw arrows and nodes with the same command?
I've found this example for drawing flowcharts:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=red!30]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, 
trapezium stretches=true, % A later addition
trapezium left angle=70, 
trapezium right angle=110, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
text width=3cm, 
draw=black, 
fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};

\node (pro2a) [process, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Process 2a
text text text text
text text text 
text text text};

\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

They have a separate block that draws arrows at the end. But most of these arrows can be derived just from the node order, can such arrows be drawn within the commands that draw nodes? Like in the \draw command with -- between nodes?
Update:
Looks like the thing I want, being able to draw the blocks and arrows in the right order, is impossible. Because you don't have the next block defined when you are trying to add an arrow between node definitions. As in this pseudo-code:
\draw
++(0,-1) node (a)
arrow to (b)
++(0,-1) node (b)
arrow to (c)
++(0,-1) node (c)

This would be also more useful that the example above if it's possible:
\draw
++(0,-1) node (a)
++(0,-1) node (b)
arrow from (a) to (b)
++(0,-1) node (c)
arrow from (b) to (c)
++(0,-1) node (d)
arrow from (c) to (d)
++(-1,0 node (e)
arrow from (c) to (e)


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

arrows library and tikzstyle is deprecated.

I'm new to tikz and KtikZ complained about the lines you've mentioned so I've removed them. I guess it adds similar lines automatically.

You need to name the nodes with the (...) syntax or name=... option to be able to draw from the border. So splitting it up in sections is the probably the best way. If you want you could combine it in one \draw like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={-Stealth},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrow] (0,0) node[draw]{A} -| (3,2) node[draw]{B};
\draw[arrow, yshift=-3cm] (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A} (3,2) node[draw, name=B] {B} (A) -| (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Trying to make it work with more than two nodes...

I can not recommend any of this, and I do not know if it can be done simpler as I have never been forced to do anything like this. -but her is a way: \draw[->] (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A} (3,2) node[draw, name=B] {B} (4,3) node[draw, name=C] {C} (A) edge[to path={-|(\tikztotarget)}] (B) (B) -| (C);

Looks like the thing I want, being able to draw the blocks and arrows in the right order, is impossible. Because you don't have the next block defined when you are trying to add an arrow between block definitions. As in \draw node arrow node arrow node arrow where each entity is on the next line. Also I've discovered that the relative positioning with ++(0,-1) is quite useful. If you want you can try improving your answer by drawing the blocks one under another and arrows being downwards.

I've added the pseudo-code to the question

The graphs library's syntax comes close.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs}
\tikzset{
  hv/.style={to path={-|(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  vh/.style={to path={|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzgraphsset{
  manual grid placement/.style={
    nodes={alias=mgp@last}, no placement,
    L/.style={shift=(mgp@last), shift=( left:1)},
    R/.style={shift=(mgp@last), shift=(right:1)},
    D/.style={shift=(mgp@last), shift=( down:1)},
    U/.style={shift=(mgp@last), shift=(   up:1)},
    go/.code={%
      \setcounter{pgf@counta}{0}\setcounter{pgf@countb}{0}%
      \@tfor\@temp:=##1\do{%
        \if\@temp L\addtocounter{pgf@counta}{-1}
          \else\if\@temp R\addtocounter{pgf@counta}{1}%
            \else\if\@temp U\addtocounter{pgf@countb}{1}%
              \else\if\@temp D\addtocounter{pgf@countb}{-1}\fi\fi\fi\fi}%
      \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{mgp@last}{center}}%
      \pgftransformshift{\pgfqpointxy{\value{pgf@counta}}{\value{pgf@countb}}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz \matrix[column sep=1em]{
  \graph[manual grid placement]{A -> B[D]     -> C[D] }; &
  \graph[manual grid placement]{A -> B[go=DD] -> C[D] ->[hv, red] D[go=RUUU]};\\};
\end{document}

Output


If all you want is to draw a chain that's going down, the chains library can do this very well, though, the graphs library can do this relatively simple as well. The graphs.standard library does support any arbitrary PGFFor list as well.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, graphs, graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz[start chain=going below, on grid, every on chain/.append style={join=by ->}]
  \foreach \A in {A, ..., F}
    \node[on chain]{\A};

\tikz\graph[grow down]{A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F};

\tikz\graph[grow down, ->]{subgraph P_n[V={A, ..., F}]};
\end{document}

Output

